# Scala: Lambda as a body of the function

Tags: scala, lambda

What is the possible practical usecase for the following type of definitions

```
type Set = Int => Boolean

def union(s: Set, t: Set): Set = { x => (contains(s, x) || contains(t, x)) }
```

above the body of the union is a lambda function.

Comment: Hint: what is the return type of `union`?

Comment: I know Int => Boolean, but I dont see when we can use such an implementation. and what is `x` in this case

Comment: There are two ways to define a set: enumerate all elements or provide a function that tells you whether the element is in the set or not (this is called the characteristic function of the set). This is an implementation of sets using the characteristic function.

Comment: My question was more related to Scala, I just used Set's code snippet to illustrate it, 1. When is the practical usecase for lambda as a body of the function 2. how do we invoke the union function, how the `x` Int will be passed as a parameter (sorry for being naive)

Comment: Coursera course, again. And ignoring the honor code, again?

Comment: Did it look like I was asking people answer for the exercise. I thought I was trying to understand things more conceptually and in depth

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> 1. When is the practical usecase for lambda as a body of the function

Read about [Higher order functions](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Higher-order_function)

> 2. how do we invoke the union function,

`Set` is a function that takes an Int and returns boolean. Union takes two Sets, and returns a third Set. So we need two Set instances first (two functions).

```
scala> type Set = Int => Boolean
defined type alias Set

scala> def contains(s: Set, x: Int): Boolean = s(x) // I assumed this
contains: (s: Set, x: Int)Boolean

scala> def union(s: Set, t: Set): Set = { x => (contains(s, x) || contains(t, x)) }
union: (s: Set, t: Set)Set

scala> val oneSet: Set = (x: Int) => x == 1
oneSet: Set = <function1>

scala> val twoSet: Set = (x: Int) => x == 2
twoSet: Set = <function1>

scala> val oneUnionTwo: Set = union(oneSet, twoSet)
oneUnionTwo: Set = <function1>
```

Now we have a third Set, which is union of `oneSet` and `twoSet`

> how the x Int will be passed as a parameter

Since `oneUnionTwo` is basically a function that takes Int. `x` is the only parameter of this function/Set. You can pass it by invoking the Set `oneUnionTwo`

```
scala> oneUnionTwo(1)
res0: Boolean = true

scala> oneUnionTwo(2)
res1: Boolean = true

scala> oneUnionTwo(3)
res2: Boolean = false
```